# Crash in v8 when converting exception to string

Tags: v8

I am attempting to do some error checking to detect if a javascript callback function called from C++ generates any errors.  This code crashes on the v8::String::Utf8Value constructor and I'm at a loss to figure out why.

```
v8::Locker locker;
v8::HandleScope scope;
v8::TryCatch tryCatch;

v8::Persistent<v8::Function> func = static_cast<PieMenu*> (info.Packet->Control)->m_callback_functions[info.Packet->Integer];
v8::Handle<v8::Value> v =   func->Call ((func), 0, NULL);

if (tryCatch.HasCaught()) {  
    v8::String::Utf8Value exception_str(tryCatch.Exception());
    if (exception_str.length() > 0) {
        wxLogVerbose(std::string(*exception_str).c_str());
    }
}
```

The error is "Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000027".  This leads me to suspect a bad pointer in the exception object, but I'm not sure where else to look. Here is the stack trace:

```
v8.dll!v8::internal::Execution::ToString(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object> obj={...}, bool * exc=0x00000000027be8a0) 
v8.dll!v8::Value::ToString()
v8.dll!v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value(v8::Handle<v8::Value> obj={...})
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and the latest trunk v8 code.

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm having a very similar problem where tryCatch.HasCaught() returns true. Furthermore tryCatch.Exception().IsEmpty() is false, but   String::Utf8Value exception(tryCatch->Exception()) == NULL.

Answer (score 0):

From the memory address, it very much looks like as if tries to read an attribute from an object which points to `NULL`.

I think your `Call` call is wrong. I remember that I had similar problems when passing `NULL` as the third parameter, even when you pass `0` arguments. Try this:

```
v8::Handle<v8::Value> argv;
func->Call ((func), 0, &argv);
```